# Route with children cannot be match, when navigating to it

Tags: typescript, angular

Good day. I can't understand how new routes with children work in Angular 2 rc 4. 
I want to route to **TestComponent**, which have child, but error "**cannot match any route 'test'**" appear. I do routing this way: `this.guide.navigate(['test']);`.
This is how I declare my routes:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LogInComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'pin',      
        component: PinComponent,    },
    {
       path: 'test',
       component: TestComponent,
       children: [
        {
            path: '/:page',
            component: FoodComponent
        }
      ]
    }  
]

export const mainRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

I cannot use some page by default in test (like "path: '/'") because its children are like tabs and their list loading in TestComponent's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things

- add `pathMatch: 'full',` to the first route, otherwise for example `/ping` will search for child route `ping` in `LogInComponent`
- add a default route to `test` that redirects to some default id or some dummy component. Angular doesn't like if a component has `<router-outlet>` but no route to add a component.

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: LogInComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'pin',      
        component: PinComponent,    },
    {
       path: 'test',
       component: TestComponent,
       children: [
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'myDefaultId'
            // or 
            // component: DummyComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/:page',
            component: FoodComponent
        }
      ]
    }  
];
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Is there any way to not use default route?

Comment: As far as I know not.